# Index out the subsequent row with an identical value in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have the following matrix named `test`:

```
            High Thresh Sig
2007-02-27 19.01  11.88   1
2007-03-01 19.40  17.29   1
2007-03-02 18.63  17.29   1
2007-03-14 21.25  20.41   1
2007-06-25 17.24  16.70   1
2007-06-27 18.98  18.89   1
```

I would like to discard the row on 2007-03-02 because it has an identical value in the Thresh column as the preceding day.

I tried this:

```
test_shorter <- subset(test, diff(Thresh) !=0)
```

but it indexes out the first occurrence whereas I want to discard the second occurrence.

Comment: you were pretty close, test_shorter <- subset(test, c(1,diff(Thresh)) !=0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `duplicated` function is great for situations like this.  For example:

```
> test[!duplicated(test[,'Thresh']),]
            High Thresh Sig
2007-02-27 19.01  11.88   1
2007-03-01 19.40  17.29   1
2007-03-14 21.25  20.41   1
2007-06-25 17.24  16.70   1
2007-06-27 18.98  18.89   1
```

If you wanted the same results as what you tried, you can use the `fromLast=` argument:

```
> test[!duplicated(test[,'Thresh'], fromLast=TRUE),]
            High Thresh Sig
2007-02-27 19.01  11.88   1
2007-03-02 18.63  17.29   1
2007-03-14 21.25  20.41   1
2007-06-25 17.24  16.70   1
2007-06-27 18.98  18.89   1
```